# Calculation of an integral based on a normal distribution CDF and PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normally-distributed random variable with mean $0$ and some positive variance.

Denote $f$ as its probability density function, and $F$ as its cumulative distribution function.

I am interested in calculating
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}F(kx)f(x)\text{ d}x$$
where $k \neq 0$ is a known constant that does not depend on $x$.

How exactly would I calculate this?

When I saw this integral, I made the mistake of thinking it was $\mathbb{E}[F(kX)]$, but soon realized it wasn't, as the integral does not cover all of $\mathbb{R}$, but only $(-\infty, 0)$.

No complete solutions are necessary; hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Write it as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 F(kx)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x)f(y)\mathbf{1}_{x<0}\mathbf{1}_{y<kx}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^2(x,y)
$$
and $\{x<0, y<kx\}$ can be easily described in polars.